# Widget shows "App Isn't Installed" Toast in ICS

Tags: android, android-widget

I've created a widget that works fine on my Galaxy Nexus via Eclipse, however when I create a signed apk, uninstall the debug version from the phone, and install the new apk and try to place it on the homescreen I get the following Toast message: "App isn't installed".

Any ideas why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like gremlins... Reboot phone and try it? Make sure you allow applications from unknown sources (Settings->Security->Allow Unknown Sources) and install your signed apk. If that fails try patting your head while standing on one foot and placing the widget with your nose :D

Comment: Reboot I will! I'll be back to confirm if that was it or not.

Comment: Uninstall -> reboot -> install...  but same result =[

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Actually I've just found out what went wrong. I'm making several widgets based on the same code, and right before building I refactored and changed the package name. I missed updating the "android:configure" field in the appwidget-provider xml, so this was causing the configuration activity to "not be found".

Answer (score 28):

I just had this problem and the solution was something I don't see mentioned here: I had changed the activity I used to configure my widget, but had forgotten to add an intent filter for it to my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity android:name="com.mypackage.ConfigureWidget" 
          android:label="@string/configureWidget">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 9):

The same problem was in my app also. What I did is that I just remove the "android:configure" field from the appwidget-provider xml and it started continue work properly.

Comment: good. works now. but how you trigger the configure screen now ?

Answer (score 1):

check whether you have given 'maxSdkVersion' parameter in your manifest..This may give you an error with a particular device...Better give targetSdkVersion instead....

Answer (score 0):

In case it can help other for my mistake
I wrongly added android:exported="false" and always made my configuration activity not popup
the exported has to be true in order for widget config to work

In summary, please make sure below
1) activity android:name is really pointing to the correct package name, esp you use ".widget.xxxxxActivity"  (be careful of the full stop)
2) android:exported="true"
3) your config activity has below

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

4) inside your appwidget-provider, make sure android:configure="your correct config activity in step 1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with this problem , Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11187572/3763837 i could fix the issue.By default it was 21 and i changed to 19. Now app is working good.
  `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`